# Facebook API - OAuth issue changes

Tags: facebook, oauth

Ok, I am looking to make some updates to my (running for some months now) Facebook app. I have a test app I created for it for it. The appId and appSecret are set correctly. I have put the domain of my test server into "App Domains". I have added my IP address to the "Server IP Whitelist." I am currently logged into Facebook as the app owner. But I am getting the dreaded:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

I can find no place on the App management screens that reference OAuth - I haven't looked here for a long time, because the app has been running well.

At this point, all I'm trying to do is get the Login button to show, hoping 
that getting past that will set me up.

Any ideas? Suggestions?
thanks...

Comment: Products -> Facebook Login is where those settings are located now.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that change - had to add the product "Facebook Login" before it was visible. It was there, I guess, since it had (the old) data in it, but for some reason it wasn't already "in" the app. Sigh. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks I was running into the same problem.